# Polkadot totalIssuance vs adding up all total account balance is not the same

Tags: polkadot

when i take a snapshot of DOT accounts and add the total balances i get slightly less than the totalIssuance(), approx 21,499 DOT under.

Is this expected or should they be exactly the same?

how is totalIssuance calculated?

here is the script and repo to [add totals](https://github.com/DOTisDED/snapshot/blob/master/utils/addTotals.cjs), which also contains the snapshot file:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');
const path = require('path');

const snapshotFilePath = path.join(__dirname, '../dot-balances-new-dwellir5.json'); 

async function sumTotalsInSnapshot() {
    const fileStream = fs.createReadStream(snapshotFilePath);
    const rl = readline.createInterface({
        input: fileStream,
        crlfDelay: Infinity
    });

    let totalSum = BigInt(0);
    let accountCount = 0; // counter for the number of accounts processed

    for await (const line of rl) {
        if (line.trim()) { // Skip empty lines
            try {
                const accountData = JSON.parse(line);
                const total = BigInt(accountData.Total || "0");
                totalSum += total;
                accountCount++; 
            } catch (err) {
                console.error(`Error parsing line: ${err}`);
            }
        }
    }

    console.log(`sum total of 'Total' values: ${totalSum.toString()}`);
    console.log(`number of accounts processed: ${accountCount}`);
}

sumTotalsInSnapshot().catch(console.error);
```

producing: `13,956,878,645,064,514,097`

the snapshot block is:

blockNumer: `18871235`

blockHash: `0x51d501fb2aab8e611c183d14e05cd5e263729a44f89edbe6232ef5bf710910ab`

the totalIssuance() is `13,957,093,143,985,979,503`

there is a difference of `21,499 DOT`.

- When trying 300 blocks ahead of the snapshot the discrepancy is still 21,499.xxx DOT.
- When trying 4m blocks behind of the snapshot number the discrepancy is 16,991

Comment: How did you get the `accountData.total`? There isn't such a field in Substrate native code. I believe there is something wrong while you calculating this `total`.

Comment: I did free + reserved = Total 

https://github.com/DOTisDED/snapshot/blob/9c2697c10332578bdb90ed800ed344faec11aa60/snapshot/snapshot-dot.cjs#L114C11-L114C11

I also checked by adding all free and all reserve then adding after, still the same discrepency.

Comment: Hm, could be a bug. I re-measured it and got `21446.7999589735`.

Comment: thanks for measuring yourself... what kind of bug are you referring to? did you measure with my script or with your own script? and what was the blocknumber you measured it at?

Comment: Own script. Not sure what it could be, maybe its also expected. I asked some other people. But there were some migrations in the past that could mess with stuff. Block number must have been 30 min old or so.

Comment: ok interesting. perhaps it was from genesis let me snapshot block 1 lol

Comment: block 1 was 0 with6  accounts 
block 100,000 was 150,633, 844 and totalIssuance shows the same. which proves that "its not me its you polkadot"

Comment: Can you find the first block where it fails with binary search on the block number? That would help, thanks!

Comment: at block 313222, an account(s) lost almost exactly 20,000 DOT. Before this time, the discrepancy is 0 and after this time, the discrepancy differs.

Answer (score 1):

After doing a binary search, the discrepancy between summing accounts and the totalIssuance() began at block `313222` on polkadot. This was almost exactly 20,000 DOT.

After this block the number does differ. For example, block `18871235` is 24,999 DOT discrepancy.

Comment: Thanks for the block number! I see account `11gh7WpYe5CKN82opEkrZUJsHeaFZa3pdEkEZFSMkV3k1Xj` was deleted with that much balance.

Comment: if we can find out why we should propose a tip to replenish the account (minus finders fee : D)

Answer (score 0):

Good find!

I opened an issue in the runtimes repo https://github.com/polkadot-fellows/runtimes/issues/147 to correct it.
Could be that there are more reasons and that the 20K are just one part of it. Many thanks for reporting it here.